# Pylance ругается на вызов Union аргумента функции

Tags: python, typing, pylance

У меня есть следующий код как минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Optional, TypeVar, Union
from random import choice

T1 = TypeVar("T1")

class qux(Generic[T1]):
    def foo(self) -> Callable[[T1], None]:
        def foo_wrapper(arg:T1):
            print(f'Foo wrapper called with argument {arg}')

        return foo_wrapper

    def bar(self) -> Callable[[], None]:
        def bar_wrapper():
            print('Bar wrapper called without arguments')
        
        return bar_wrapper
        
    def buzz(self, func:Union[Callable[[T1], Any], Callable[[], Any]], arg: Optional[T1] = None):
        if arg:
            func(arg)
        else:
            func()
            
    def choice_impl(self, flag:bool):
        if flag:
            return self.foo()
        else:
            return self.bar()
    
qux_instance = qux()
value = None
if choice((True, False)):
    value = 42

flag = value is not None

implementation = qux_instance.choice_impl(flag=flag)
if flag:
    qux_instance.buzz(func=implementation, arg=value)
else:
    qux_instance.buzz(func=implementation)
```

Pylance ругается на строку 21:

```
Expected 0 positional arguments  (parameter) arg: T1@qux
```

и 23:

```
Expected 1 more positional argument (parameter) func: ((T1@qux) -> Any) | (() -> Any)
```

потому что он не знает, какая сигнатура у аргумента `func` функции `buzz` будет на момент вызова. Хотя этот код всегда выполняется без ошибок. Как мне решить эту проблему? Это баг Pylance или это связанно с проблемой останова? Или это у меня руки кривые?

Comment: скопируйте ошибку пожалуйста

Comment: Версия Python 3.10.5

Comment: Статический анализатор не определит тут какой вариант типа из Union фактически имеет func. На вашем примере я бы просто устранил неоднозначность, например всегда передавал бы Callable без аргументов, а вызов делал снаружи. Или передавал бы аргументы списком, а не как Optional.

Comment: Или вообще сделать два отдельных метода с разной сигнатурой. Это не связано с проблемой останова, это связано с проблемой скрещивания ужа с ежом - статической типизации с динамической. Чисто технически ваш код вполне рабочий, но чтобы прикрутить к нему аннотации типа, нужно свернуть мозг, и переписать код так, как будто это статически типизированный язык, как Java, например.

Comment: @insolor в очередной раз убеждаюсь, что строгая типизация лучше динамической.

Comment: Не лучше, просто она другая.

Comment: Скажем так, при динамической типизации больше возможностей для самовыражения (реализации своих идей), но потом может быть проблематично на эту реализацию натянуть строгие рамки статической типизации. А в языках со строгой типизацией вам заранее нужно впихнуть свои идеи в рамки строгой типизации.

Comment: @insolor я бы хотел в данном случае явно указать Pylance, что я знаю, что делаю, но при этом не использовать `# type: ignore`. Что-то вроде `assert isinstance(func, Callable[[T1], Any])`. Но только, чтобы эта строка не выполнялась в интерпретаторе.

Comment: Ну, можно использовать cast из typing: `cast(Callable[[T1], Any], func)(arg)`, `cast(Callable[[], Any], func)()` . Но считайте что вы лишаетесь гарантии - статический анализатор никак не проверит, что передана функция именно с одним аргументом или без них.

Comment: @insolor Прекрасно! Это то, что я искал. Если вы оформите это как ответ, я отмечу его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) из модуля `typing`:

```
    def buzz(self, func:Union[Callable[[T1], Any], Callable[[], Any]], arg: Optional[T1] = None):
        if arg:
            cast(Callable[[T1], Any], func)(arg)
        else:
            cast(Callable[[], Any], func)()
```

Но это по сути отключает защиту, статический анализатор никак не сможет проверить соответствие, что вы передали функцию с одним аргументом и аргумент для нее или функцию без аргументов, и не передали аргумент.